# How to make a POST request work with link tag?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, passport.js

In my view file:

```
<a href="/logout" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary left-button">Logout</a>
```

In my app.js file:

```
app.post('/logout', function(req, res, next){
  req.logout(function(err) {
    if (err) { return next(err); }
    res.redirect('/');
  });
});
```

One helpful suggestion was to use a form tag but how can it be done with a link tag?

Comment: Is there any specific reason that you want to use a POST request? You could use `app.get('/logout ...`

Comment: I'm working with Passport.js and according to their documentation using POST is preferable to GET as it prevents accidental or malicious logouts. Although, I've learned that I need to change link to form tag but someone mentioned that JavaScript can be used to make POST request work with link. I'm just wondering how it would look like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If in any case you want to use a POST request, you can do it using AJAX request. Remove link and add an `onclick` action. That way, when you click the Logout button, you will call the `logout` function

```
<a onclick="logout()" role="button" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary left-button">Logout</a>
```

And create the logout function which will perform the POST request

```
<script>
const logout = () => {
    fetch('/logout', {method: 'POST'})
    .then((result) => {
        if (result.status === 200) {
            // successful logout, you can go to login page
            window.location = '/login'
        } else {
            console.error('Server error, logout failed')
        }
    })
    .catch((err) => console.error(err))
}
</script>
```